# Why is my water softener hammering during recharge?

Tags: water-softener, water-hammer

My water softener is water hammering during recharge.

Any thoughts on what might need to be fixed?

[image: water softener]

Answer (score 1):

Water hammer occurs when water travels along long straight plumbing pipes and comes to an abrupt stop. When the water flow stops instantly the forward momentum slams into (most likely) some 90° pipe fitting at the end of the long run.  Others may have different suggestions, but to my knowledge the only way to stop the water hammer is either add pipe elbows to the long straight pipe run, or add a water hammer arrestor near the end of the long straight run.  In any case, it should be addressed because water hammer can cause stress fractures in your plumbing leading to a failure and water damage.

[image]
[image]

Comment: My plumbing is pex. There are 90 degree elbows right before and after the water softener that I thought were rather arbitrary - see pic at link. What is considered long?  http://imgur.com/IBWXW4G

Comment: So the elbows that are in your lines now are to resolve the problem of the inlet and outlet ports being backwards from the way the pipes are run coming down the wall.  I would think the elbows on the inlet side would reduce the hammer, but nonetheless...  I included a couple of photos that hopefully explain a little better of how a water hammer arrestor works.